# Good books on the divisor sum function $\sigma(n)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, textbook-recommendation, divisors-multiples

I would like gain detailed knowledge about properties of the divisor sum function $\sigma(n)$, special equation that have been studied (e.g. $\sigma(n) = 2n$ perfect numbers, ...) and progress that was made in the past centuries.

I am interested in arithmetic functions in general so the books mentioned in this question [Good books on Arithmetic Functions ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13107/good-books-on-arithmetic-functions)  is already a good start.

However, it would be great if you could recommend a book or a comprehensive paper that introduces/summarizes knowledge about the $\sigma(n)$ function.

Answer (score 5):

For me a very good source for those matters, comprehensive in many aspects and adding enlightening notes and exercises, is

> Tenenbaum G., *Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number
>   Theory*, Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, Cambridge
>   University Press, 1995

It has just been reedited by the AMS. Moreover, he also wrote a book *Divisors*, at Cambridge Tracts. Despite I don't know what is inside, it would be worth a look.

Answer (score 3):

Sándor, Jó.; Mitrinović, D. S. & Crstici, B. Handbook of number theory. I Springer, 2006

This book describes a lot of results concerning almost all arithmetical functions.

Comment: There is also the Handbook of number theory II, by the same authors, I think.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** try to check [this online book](https://books.google.dz/books?id=DYEXAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=best+books+for+sum+divisor+function&source=bl&ots=stuyvM_P2l&sig=ahjZEIrNT4ICHHsw4zGjEveMZZY&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicid3or9LYAhWIshQKHQo7CXw4ChDoAQhIMAM#v=onepage&q=best%20books%20for%20sum%20divisor%20function&f=false) under this title **The math encyclopedia of smarandach type notion** in number theory include also arithmitic function , And bellow papers  ,  However they  include iterate sum of divisor function, but you w'ill find solution of your problem , papers include " meta perfect number:"

**Cohen, Graeme L., and Herman JJ te Riele. "Iterating the sum-of-divisors function."**

**Kátai, I. "On the prime power divisors of the iterates of $\phi(n)$ and $\sigma(n)$, Šiauliai**

**Math." Semin 4.12 (2009): 125-143**
**Experimental Mathematics 5.2 (1996): 91-100**.